# What does "How do you find life in Japan?" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

**What does "How do you find life in Japan?" mean?**

I'm asking this question because I've looked up the definition of life on the Cambridge dictionary website and the closest thing that I could find was "a particular type or part of someone’s experience:" and the example that they gave which was the closest to the meaning of life that I want was "She appreciates life in the United States." where's the link https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/life. So what part of someone's experience is life there referring to, if that's the meaning of life in that sentence that I want to know?

I've also looked up the word on the collins dictionary and the definition that I found was "You can use life to refer to the things that people do and experience that are characteristic of a particular place, group, or activity.", but the problem is that I don't know exactly what they are talking about, since it could be about a broad range of topics, Could someone give me an example of an answer to that question?

Comment: It means the **quality of** life. Answers to the question could be "It is exciting", "It is dull", "It is safe", etc.

Comment: Just as *I **find** that disgusting!* means *I **think** that is disgusting!*, you could say *I find life in Japan exciting,* to mean *I think [my] life in Japan is exciting,*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica my question is about the meaning of **life** in that sentence it's not about find.

Comment: Fair enough. But you could have used a dictionary for that, not ELL.

Comment: "What is your opinion of the experience you have had of living in Japan?" (as a place with different customs, manners, food etc. from the person's home country).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I did, didn't read my post?

Comment: what's your life/experience in Japan like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that I don't know exactly what they are talking about,
> since it could be about a broad range of topics

That is exactly the point: it refers to ***everything***

> Could someone give me an example of an answer to that question?

You can answer about ***any aspect of life in Japan***:

> I find it quite different from everything I am used to: the food is extremely spicy, the fashion eccentric and people unpredictable.

Or you could answer:

> I find it amazing! Terrific sites, welcoming people, intriguing traditions and fascinating technology. I never get bored!

Comment: Yes, it's a conversational gambit, an open-ended question inviting the other person to talk.